# Running a script from build directory in gradle

Tags: directory, gradle

I want to run a script which is available in 'build/classes' directory, from 'build' directory. Because, my script reference a file whose path is relative to the build directory. Is it possible to make gradle to switch to build directory inside a particular task of type JavaExec? The snippet of build file is below.

```
task myrun(type:JavaExec) {     
    main = 'peep'
    args  '3'     
    classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

The peep script requires a file which is present inside build directory. Hence, i thought of switching to 'build' directory inside this task 'myrun'.

Any help?

Comment: According to http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html there is workingDir parameter. The default value is project dir. So you should change it to `build`

Comment: Yes, adding workingDir = buildDir, worked. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I will transform comment to answer if it is not duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html there is `workingDir` parameter. And the default value for it is project dir.

The solution would be:

```
task myrun(type:JavaExec) {     
    main = 'peep'
    args  '3'     
    classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    workingDir = buildDir
}
```